# Formula that counts days worked while excluding overlapping or partial overlapping days in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm attempting to create a schedule that counts the number of days an employee has worked while ignoring the days that overlap. I have a spreadsheet with all employee activities that gets populated dynamically. Some of these activities overlap, some of them partially overlap.
It seems like everything I tried today by searching through forums doesn't account for

a) multiple employees
 
b) dynamic formulas (x number of rows, x number of employees)
 
c) partial overlap

I attached a spreadsheet with the desired result in Column G
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjbjXFCYj1qXrVVGNnhOj11asxT_o1xHWXerRqAl1UQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♠"&INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)&"♦"&
 SPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)&"♣", 
 DAYS(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1), INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1))+1), "♣")+
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(DAYS(C2:C, B2:B)+1)))-1))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), "where Col2 > 4000", 0)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Where can I learn this magic? Do you mind teaching me how would I add an additional check here so that on top of the current formula it also splits the days based on activity type? Please check the spreadsheet.

Comment: there's an extra column that specifies the activity type (Column E). Notice that one value is set to "Vacation" (E9), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I see, check this if it's sufficient: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjbjXFCYj1qXrVVGNnhOj11asxT_o1xHWXerRqAl1UQ/edit#gid=0&range=I2

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I truly appreciate it!